# Some cached elements are not deleted after cache evictAll()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

This is a Spring + JPA + Hibernate + EhCache application. I am facing some issues with cache (or I am assuming that is due to cache configuration). I am trying to cache some objects (it works fine, I can see in the cache statistics). The problem is that I want to flush the cache with a button if, for example, I need to update database directly to change some information from an external application.

The ExaminationForm entity is something like:

```
@Entity
public class ExaminationForm implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7235473414679474757L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 150)
private String name;

// Duration in minutes
private Integer duration;

//Getters and setters and other stuff...
```

Of course there are lot of more entities, but are working correctly and therefore obviated in the question. The DAO is more or less like:

```
@Repository
public class ExaminationFormDao {

@Override
@Cacheable(value = "examinations", key = "#id")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, readOnly = false)
public ExaminationForm get(Long id) {
    return super.get(id);
}

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, readOnly = false)
public List<EntityClass> getAll() {
    CriteriaQuery<EntityClass> query = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(getEntityClass());
    query.select(query.from(getEntityClass()));
    try {
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(query).getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        return new ArrayList<EntityClass>();
    }
}

@Caching(evict = { @CacheEvict(value = "examinations", allEntries = true) })
public void evictAllCache() {
    getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
}
```

In my applicationContext.xml of spring, I define the cache configuration as follows:

```
<!--  Cache Configuration  -->
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache" />
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml" p:shared="true" />
```

Hibernate related data only contains connection information and C3P0 variables. Therefore I do not copy here to avoid to much code.

With the ehcache.xml configuration as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache name="usmocache">     
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />
<defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="0"
    overflowToDisk="false" statistics="true" />
<cache name="examinations" copyOnRead="true" copyOnWrite="true" 
    maxElementsInMemory="2000" eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="1200" overflowToDisk="false"
    diskPersistent="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" statistics="true" />
</ehcache>
```

There are more data, but I do not want to copy thousands of lines of code to ask this question. If required, I can put more info later.

Check that for evicting all classes I clean the region and also I execute `getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();` to be sure that is removed. When I press the button I call the evictAllCache() in both DAOs. Probably is not the best approach and is redundant, but I am trying different approach without success. Also `getAll()` has not any `@Cacheable` annotation.

The problem is when I access to the getAll method of the DAO. First time, with Hibernate and cache debug set to on I get:

```
SQL [qtp684428083-26] - select examinatio0_.ID as ID1_12_, examinatio0_.duration as duration2_12_, examinatio0_.name as name3_12_ from examination_form examinatio0_
TRACE BasicExtractor [qtp684428083-26] - extracted value ([ID1_12_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
TRACE BasicExtractor [qtp684428083-26] - extracted value ([duration2_12_] : [INTEGER]) - [15]
TRACE BasicExtractor [qtp684428083-26] - extracted value ([name3_12_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Examination1Name]
TRACE BasicExtractor [qtp684428083-26] - extracted value ([ID1_12_] : [BIGINT]) - [2]
TRACE BasicExtractor [qtp684428083-26] - extracted value ([duration2_12_] : [INTEGER]) - [15]
TRACE BasicExtractor [qtp684428083-26] - extracted value ([name3_12_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Examination2Name]
...
```

That is the expected behaviour. Is populating all Examinations data when getting all examinatios. But if I clean the cache, and execute again this method, I only get:

```
SQL [qtp684428083-26] - select examinatio0_.ID as ID1_12_, examinatio0_.duration as duration2_12_, examinatio0_.name as name3_12_ from examination_form examinatio0_
TRACE BasicExtractor [qtp684428083-26] - extracted value ([ID1_12_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
TRACE BasicExtractor [qtp684428083-26] - extracted value ([ID1_12_] : [BIGINT]) - [2]
...
```

Only IDs are retrieved. As in the GUI I can see the name and duration of each examination, means that the information is already available and hibernate does not need to retrieve it again. Therefore I am assuming that is cached somewhere.

The questions are:

1. How can I force to reload all these data from database again?
2. Why getAll() is using cache if there is no annotation in the DAO's
   method neither in the entity to say that it must be cacheable.
3. What is wrong in my `evictAllCache()` method?

Obviously I am wrong somewhere but I am not able to find where.

Comment: I also have checked some posts related to L1 cache to be sure that this is not the issue, but seems that the L1 is flushed time ago.

Comment: Your `evictAllCache` method calls `super.evictAllCache()` but your `ExaminationFormDao` doesn't seem to extend anything.  Are you using aspectj for compile-time weaving?  Also, unless you plug ehCache into hibernate directly as a hibernate cache provider (which I don't see in what you've provided) then hibernate is not using it/using its own instance.  In short, your `evictAllCache` method probably needs to clear hibernate's cache explicitly, e.g. by using http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear()

Comment: You are mixing 2 different things. Spring Caching and Hibernate 2nd level caching both are different and use different caches, so clearing one doesn't mean you are clearing the other. I would strongly suggest to only use a single approach and not try to mix 2 different caching strategies.

Comment: The super.evictAllCache() is an error of copy&paste. I am trying to simplify the hierarchy. The same class have again the same method that directly does: `getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();`

Comment: The idea of mixing Hibernate 2nd level cache and Spring caching seems to be the problem. I am migrating the code from hibernate 2nd level cache to Spring cache and it is possible that some changes are not correctly done. I will remove Spring cache and let Hibernate Cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your queries are getting the objects from first level cache. Try to clean it with `getEntityManager().clear();`

Comment: I really do not realize that the level 1 cache of the entity manager has so long life that can persist among screens in my GUI. Probably it is due to the use of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`. Now, clearing the L1 cache with the command described is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Also, as suggested I need to remove one of the two caches technologies.